# Passing credentials to reporting services via classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, asp-classic

I would like to pass the credentials of SQL Server Reporting Services via classic ASP as currently the user is asked to enter username and password each time he try to access the report.

Can I pass it as a parameter from the page using the POST method?

As this code :

```
<body>
  <form id="frmRender" action="ReportViewer" method="post" target="Main">
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="Password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="View Report" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine. I'm not sure how you're calling your SSRS reports, but if you have some API, you should be able to get them from `Dim ID = Request.QueryString("ID")` and `Dim Password = Request.QueryString("Password")`. I would change your password text input to an actual password input like `<input type="password" name="Password" value=""/>` so that it shows up as ***** when they're typing it into the form. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/cc864bc8-1225-489c-b901-8016d656a5db) is a URL you might find helpful.